# How to create an appropriately-sized array for the number of lines in a text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to read in a text file line by line. On each line there are two double numbers separated by a comma (representing x,y points). I would like to put them in two arrays of doubles (one containing the x-points and the other the y-points) in order that they are in the file. The arrays should be the same size as the number of points there are in the file (i.e. the number of lines in the file).

The files could have different numbers of points, so I do not want to declare a fixed size for all files. How do I go about doing this?

**EDIT**:

There is something wrong with the way I am doing this:

```
BufferedReader input; 

ArrayList<Double> xpointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> ypointArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
try {
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        line = input.readLine();
        String[] splitLine = line.split(",");

        double xValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]);
        double yValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]);

        xpointArrayList.add(xValue);
        ypointArrayList.add(yValue);
    }
    input.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {

    }

    double[] xpoints = new double[xpointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < xpoints.length; i++) {
        xpoints[i] = xpointArrayList.get(i);
    }
    double[] ypoints = new double[ypointArrayList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < ypoints.length; i++) {
        ypoints[i] = ypointArrayList.get(i);
    }
```

When I do the Array.toSring call on the xpoints and the ypoints array. It only has one number. For example in the file:

1,2 / 3,4 / 0,5

It only has 3.0 for the xpoints array and 4.0 for the ypoints array. Where is it going wrong?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: Why are you reading before while loop. It will skip first line of your file. More over how can you even compile your code with following line in your program.
String = input.readLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just making a single `ArrayList` of type `Point`. An `ArrayList` will grow to the size of the content, so it should be as simple as doing something like this (psuedocode)...

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

for (each line of the file){
    String line = file.readLine();
    String[] splitLine = line.split(",");

    double xValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]);
    double yValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]);

    points.add(new Point(xValue,yValue));
}
```

The `Point` class is designed as a container for 2 `double` values, used to represent any abstract point, which should suit your need perfectly. Refer to the [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) documentation.

If you really need to use 2 arrays, my recommendation is to use an `ArrayList<Double>`...

```
ArrayList<Double> xPoints = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> yPoints = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (each line of the file){
    String line = file.readLine();
    String[] splitLine = line.split(",");

    double xValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[0]);
    double yValue = Double.parseDouble(splitLine[1]);

    xPoints.add(xValue);
    yPoints.add(yValue);
}
```

Refer to the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) documentation for more information about this.

If you really need to use arrays, you can convert the `ArrayList` to an array like this...

```
Double[] xArray = (Double[])xPoints.toArray();
Double[] yArray = (Double[])yPoints.toArray();
```

Comment: I wanted to split them because I will be doing some calculations with them.

Comment: In that case, use 2 `ArrayList<Double>`, so it will still grow to the correct size. If you really need an actual array, you can call the `toArray()` method on the `ArrayList` when you've finished populating it.

Comment: Could you please expand your sample code for how to add the points, eliminating the comma? - x,y - Would I still need to use `split(",")` and Double.parseDouble(xpoint[0],ypoint[1]);?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to do it. I have just updated my code to display this.

Comment: I updated my current code above. I am getting stuck though. What do I need to change/add?

Comment: The split line might not work, you don't need it to be that complicated, it should only need a single comma like in my code. Also the parseDouble can only take a single value, not both at the same time.

Comment: I have fixed everything. It is complaining about the toArray statements though.

Comment: Do you know how to go from Double to double offhand?

Comment: The best you can do is have a Double[] array, you won't be able to get a double[] array. You can get a double for each value individually as you need them, by calling the `doubleValue()` method. E.g. `myArray[0].doubleValue();`

Comment: I actually found a loop that converts the Double to double. Not exactly the most efficient way of doing things, but I already have the rest of my program built for the primitive double. Now I am trying to deal with the NullPointerException that you get when it reaches the end of the file and still actually run the rest of my program. When it reaches the end of the file and I catch the NPE, it does not return to the `try` clause. When I put the code outside of the last catch clause though, it cannot find the symbols inside the try. So I am trying to figure it all out.

Comment: I put up my current code. It is not quite working. Do you see where it is going wrong?

Comment: Nevermind. I asked it in another question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. You are asking for a variable sized array. Use an ArrayList. You don't have to specify an initial size and it will grow however large you need it to. Additionally, it might be worth your while to make a point class to handle this data. That way you can have a list of points.

```
public class Point
{
private double x;
private double y;

public point(double x, double y)
{
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

public double getX()
{
return x;
}

public double getY()
{
return y;
}
}

List<Point> myPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

And, if your just really like regular arrays:
     myPoints.toArray();

Answer (score 1):

As you already opened and reading from file simple way is to put counter in loop and read all the lines.

```
  int count =0;
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      count++;
      System.out.println( strLine + " : "+ count);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

FileObject.length() will return the number of bites in a file, divide that by the size of a double type integer (8 bytes?) and you'll have the number of double variables stored in your file, divide that number by 2 again (or divide your original number by 4)and you should have the number of lines in your file, if I understand your question correctly.